# CSS Any embedded image type that does NOT use URL as a predecessor?

Tags: css, sass, less

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while, is there an type of image or url embedding for CSS or its language derivatives (SASS, LESS etc) that do not use this specific syntax?

```
url:(foo.png) # with or without quotation
```

I know that SASS can and does use

```
asset-url('foo.png', image);
```

but I am counting this as a match (due to my regular expression formula that this is for)

Specific things that I am looking for would be for instance how HTML handles urls with both href and src, *though this is unrelated* I would like to use it as an example due to the fact that it utilizes urls in different ways. Thanks for taking a minute to quiz over this one =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS can only reference images by the `url()` function (even embedded image data is a data url).  However, compile to CSS languages like LESS and SASS, are far less straight forward...

`asset-url()` is not a SASS native function.  It's provided by the [`sass-rails` gem](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails), and so only available in the context of a rails application.  So `asset-url()` is a custom function that is provided by a library. And you can even write your own function that abstract away calls to `url()` behind your own custom mixins.

If you want to find all image URLs referenced in some CSS, they *only* reliable way to do it is to compile it to CSS and then search through that, because that's the only way you can know for sure.  And as a bonus, this approach will work for other CSS preprocessors that you havent written a scanner for, because all you care about is CSS.

Comment: Plus one and accepted, thank you. Background on this is for a proxy portal rewrite, so I need to be able to all html/css/js links en-route (pita) I'll consider the CSS portion done now.